# How to run for-loop after def function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

Im tryin' to run the last for-loop after the def function, but it didn't run as I thought.

```
lst = [] 

print(lst)
print('The queue is now empty...')

MaxQueue = int(input('\nSet The Maximum Queue to: '))

for i in range(0, MaxQueue): 
    print(lst)
    inn = input('Enter Name: ')
    lst.append(inn)  
print('')   
print(lst) 
print('The Queue is full..')   

def get_answer(prompt):
    while True:
        answer = input(prompt)
        if answer not in ('yes','no'):
            answer = input(prompt)        
        if answer in ('yes'):
            break         
        if answer in ('no'):
            exit()
    
print(get_answer('Do you want to start seriving? '))

for i in range(MaxQueue,0):
    print(lst)
    de = input('press (enter) to serve')
    print(lst.pop(0))
```

Comment: `range(MaxQueue,0)` iterates on nothing, you can't go from a positive vlaue to zero as the defualt increment is 1, you could do  `range(MaxQueue,0, -1)` but as you don't use `i`, just do `range(MaxQueue)`

Comment: thank god @azro, u saved me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your big problem is that the `range` function is written incorrectly, you are entering the higher value before the lower value which is wrong.
Your other problems might be minor compared to this one but still very important!
make sure to **ALWAYS** check your input to avoid unexpected behaviors such as negative numbers or zero.
The fix would be:

```py
lst = [] 

print(lst)
print('The queue is now empty...')

MaxQueue = int(input('\nSet The Maximum Queue to: '))

# A loop to ensure the user will never be able to insert a value lower than 1.
while MaxQueue <= 0:
    print('Cannot receive a length lower than 1!')
    MaxQueue = int(input('\nSet The Maximum Queue to: '))

for i in range(0, MaxQueue): 
    print(lst)
    inn = input('Enter Name: ')
    lst.append(inn)

print('\n')   
print(lst) 
print('The Queue is full..')   

def get_answer(prompt):
    while True:
        answer = input(prompt)
        if answer not in ('yes','no'):
            answer = input(prompt)        
        if answer in ('yes'):
            break         
        if answer in ('no'):
            exit()
    
print(get_answer('Do you want to start seriving? (yes/no):'))

for i in range(0, MaxQueue):
    print(lst)
    input('press (enter) to serve') # no need to save input.
    print(lst.pop(0))
```

Comment: thank u so much for helping me and revise my code

Answer (score 0):

Ranges where the beginning is past the end are empty. Your `get_answer` also contains a couple of bugs.

```
lst = [] 

print(lst)
print('The queue is now empty...')

MaxQueue = int(input('\nSet The Maximum Queue to: '))

for i in range(MaxQueue): 
    print(lst)
    inn = input('Enter Name: ')
    lst.append(inn)  

print('')   
print(lst) 
print('The Queue is full..')   

def get_answer(prompt):
    answer = None # set initial value to make sure the loop runs at least once
    while answer not in ('yes', 'no'):
        answer = input(prompt)
    if answer == 'no': 
        exit()
    
get_answer('Do you want to start serving? ')

for i in range(MaxQueue):
    print(lst)
    input('press (enter) to serve')
    print(lst.pop(0))
```

For larger programs it's not usually a good idea to just `exit()` in the middle, because you might want to do other things, so we could instead use boolean logic and do something like

```
def get_answer(prompt):
    answer = None # set initial value to make sure the loop runs at least once
    while answer not in ('yes', 'no'):
        answer = input(prompt)
    return answer == 'yes'
    
if get_answer('Do you want to start serving? '):
    for i in range(MaxQueue):
        print(lst)
        input('press (enter) to serve')
        print(lst.pop(0))
```

Comment: thanks for the advice buddy, its a new tip for my little experience in python programing